# How can I remove the commas in a numeric value in R?

Tags: r

```
column19 <- 19
mdf[,column19] <- lapply(mdf[,column19],function(x){as.numeric(gsub(",", "", x))})
```

this snippet works but also results in duplicate values

Answer (score 2):

If there is only a single column, we don't need `lapply`

```
mdf[, column19] <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", mdf[, column19], fixed = TRUE))
```

---

The reason why the OP's code didn't work out as expected is because `lapply` on a single column after converting it to a `vector` (`mdf[, column19]`) and loop through each of the single element of the column and return a `list`.  Now, we are assigning the output of `list` back to that single column

```
column19 <- 19
mdf[,column19] <- lapply(mdf[,column19],function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",", "", x)))
```

> Warning message: In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , column19, value =
>   list(27, 49, 510,  :   provided 5 variables to replace 1 variables

Instead, if we want to use the same procedure either keep the `data.frame` structure by `mdf[column19]` or `mdf[, column19, drop = FALSE]` and then loop using `lapply`.  In this way, it will be a `list` with a single `vector`

```
mdf[column19] <- lapply(mdf[column19],function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",", "", x)))
```

This is more related to dropping of dimensions when using `[` on a single column or row as by default it is `drop = TRUE`.

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
mdf <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(paste(1:5, 6:10, sep=","), 
   5*20, replace = TRUE), 5, 20), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: could add `fixed=TRUE` for this one.

Comment: @Sotos  I have no problems with duping correctly, but here  the OP was using correct `gsub` on an incorrect loop.  So, I am not sure if the dupe is correct for that

Comment: Ok. I believe It is a problem that can be solved by reviewing the dupe so IMO it is correct.